# In Python, how to do group by + mutate + ifelse like R?

Tags: python, transform, dplyr

I usually use R. If I have a data like:

```
Product    Index   Value
   a         1       0.5
   a         1       0.4
   c         1       1.4
   c         2       0.75
   e         2       0.6
   f         3       0.9
```

If my R code is :

```
a <- data %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(Flag=ifelse(all(Index==1),'right','wrong'))
```

It means, I group the data by Product first. Then for each group, I will give it a new field called Flag. If Index in this group is all 1, then Flag is right, otherwise it is wrong. At the same time, all the reocrds are remained. So, The result should look like:

```
Product    Index   Value    Flag
   a         1       0.5    right
   a         1       0.4    right
   c         1       1.4    wrong
   c         2       0.75   wrong
   e         2       0.6    wrong
   f         3       0.9    wrong
```

My question is: how to do the same operations in python? I have tried, np.where, groupby, transform and other functions. I probably combine them the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using transform is an option.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'f'],
               'Index': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 
              'Value': [0.5, 0.4, 1.4, 0.75, 0.6, 0.9]})
df['Flag'] = df.groupby('Product')['Index'].transform(lambda x: 'right' if sum(x)/len(x) == 1 else 'wrong')
df
```

On a side note, if Flag values are just 'right' and 'wrong', substituting them with 0,1 values might be more efficient.

Comment: Perhaps this is more generic (can be used for strings etc):
df['Flag'] = df.groupby('Product')['Index'].transform(lambda x: 'right' if all(x==1) else 'wrong')

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great.

Comment: You can also subset with the boolean: `df['Flag'] = df.groupby('Product')['Index'].transform(lambda i: ['wrong', 'right'][all(i == 1)])`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `unique()` and `groupby()` to make sure all Products have an index of 1, and then map to your new column:

```
In [51]: df['Flag'] = df['Product'].map(df.groupby('Product')['Index'].unique().apply(lambda row: 'right' if all(row==[1]) else 'wrong'))

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
  Product  Index  Value   Flag
0       a      1   0.50  right
1       a      1   0.40  right
2       c      1   1.40  wrong
3       c      2   0.75  wrong
4       e      2   0.60  wrong
5       f      3   0.90  wrong
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean`, compare by `1` and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for values by condition:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df.groupby('Product')['Index'].transform('mean')== 1, 'right', 'Wrong')
print (df)
  Product  Index  Value   Flag
0       a      1   0.50  right
1       a      1   0.40  right
2       c      1   1.40  Wrong
3       c      2   0.75  Wrong
4       e      2   0.60  Wrong
5       f      3   0.90  Wrong
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('Product')['Index'].transform('mean'))
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.5
3    1.5
4    2.0
5    3.0
Name: Index, dtype: float64
```

---

Another solution:

First compare by `1` by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) for check if all `True`s per group and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for values by condition:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df['Index'].eq(1).groupby(df['Product']).transform('all'), 
                      'right', 'Wrong')
print (df)
  Product  Index  Value   Flag
0       a      1   0.50  right
1       a      1   0.40  right
2       c      1   1.40  Wrong
3       c      2   0.75  Wrong
4       e      2   0.60  Wrong
5       f      3   0.90  Wrong
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Index'].eq(1).groupby(df['Product']).transform('all'))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: Index, dtype: bool
```